# Entity Framework Core NodaTime grouping by date

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql, nodatime

I'm using NodaTime and Entity Framework Core and now I'm trying to group my query by date, though I'm using `Instant` as field data type. As far as I've understood, using dateColumn.Date (when using DateTime) should work and transfer query to `date_trunc('day', dateColumn)`, but how can I achieve that with NodaTime `Instant` type?

Problem I see is that Instant requires timezone to be passed in order to resolve the day, which would throw

> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to perform operations with human calendar units (e.g. days, months...), then considering using LocalDateTime instead. The idea of Instant is precisely that it doesn't support human calendar operations etc.

Something like this should work:

```cs
_ = await ctx.Blogs.GroupBy(b => b.Creation.Date).CountAsync();

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(@"...", o => o.UseNodaTime());
}

public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public LocalDateTime Creation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's what I actually expected to be the solution - do you have an example how would I do above request with LocalDateTime field?